# Docker named volumes not being created

Tags: docker, docker-run

I have a docker container that I am attempting to mount named containers to, however they do not appear to be getting created or mounted.

```
$ sudo docker run --network=host the_container \
            -v file_storage:/root/file_storage \
            -v redis_database:/var/lib/redis \
            -v mongo_database:/var/lib/mongodb
```

The container seems to run fine, however when I search for the containers, they are not being created and mounted, as they are supposed to.

```
$ sudo docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything after the image name on the `docker run` command is passed as a command to the container.

Try it this way:

```sh
sudo docker run --network=host \
            -v file_storage:/root/file_storage \
            -v redis_database:/var/lib/redis \
            -v mongo_database:/var/lib/mongodb \
            the_image
```